# Borgmatic cron job errors with python `ModuleNotFoundError`

Tags: command-line, python, cron

I am trying to set up a daily cron job which backs up some files using [borgmatic](https://torsion.org/borgmatic), but I keep getting the same error and have not been able to figure out how to fix it.

My `borgmatic` version:

```sh
$ borgmatic --version
1.3.0
```

My `/etc/cron.daily/borgmatic` file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
MAILTO="tomeraberbach@gmail.com"
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
PYTHONPATH=/home/tomeraberbach/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/bin/borgmatic
```

And its permissions:

```sh
$ ls -l /etc/cron.daily/borgmatic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root tomeraberbach 162 Apr  8 00:20 /etc/cron.daily/borgmatic*
```

However, I keep getting the following error when the job runs:

```
/etc/cron.daily/borgmatic:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/borgmatic", line 7, in <module>
    from borgmatic.commands.borgmatic import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/borgmatic/commands/borgmatic.py", line 22, in <module>
    from borgmatic.config import checks, collect, convert, validate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/borgmatic/config/convert.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ruamel import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel'
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/borgmatic exited with return code 1
```

This only happens in the cron job. Runnning `borgmatic` normally works fine.

Additionally, the `ruamel` package is definitely installed:

```sh
$ ls /home/tomeraberbach/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ruamel
yaml/
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I know cron runs in a different environment, but I am not sure how to fix this issue.

EDIT:

Changing the `PYTHONPATH=/home/tomeraberbach/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` line to `export PYTHONPATH=/home/tomeraberbach/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/bin/borgmatic` causes the script to error in a different way:

```
/etc/cron.daily/borgmatic:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/borgmatic", line 7, in <module>
    from borgmatic.commands.borgmatic import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'borgmatic'
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/borgmatic exited with return code 1
```

Comment: I wonder if it's as simple as `export PYTHONPATH=/home/tomeraberbach/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` in place of `PYTHONPATH=/home/tomeraberbach/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` ?

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that out and get back to you.

Comment: @steeldriver Tried adding `export` to the line, but now I get a different error.

Answer (score 1):

borgmatic author here. It looks like borgmatic is installed at the system level, and some of its dependencies are installed as your personal user. But the borgmatic cron job is running as root. That's the fundamental mismatch. So my recommendation would be to uninstall any borgmatic dependencies as your personal user, and reinstall them root [as per the instructions here](https://torsion.org/borgmatic/docs/how-to/set-up-backups/), with or without `--user`. Then, when you run the cron job as the root user, it should hopefully have everything in the right paths. If not, then you can try adding relevant paths to your `PYTHONPATH` as `steeldriver` suggests above. Potentially *appending* paths with `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/new/path` if necessary to avoid replacing existing paths.